# Import CSV without data being formatted to dates and numbers

Tags: excel, vba, csv, import, formatting

I am trying to make a macro that will let user import data from CSV with UTF8 encoding and all the columns defined as text (Excel usually assumes relevant data to be dates and numbers). The code that I have is given below,

```
Sub Macro1()

    Const sName As String = "9 1copy"
    Dim strFile As String
    strFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.csv),*.csv", , "Please select text file...")
    
    On Error GoTo delQuery
        ThisWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="9 1copy", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents(strFile),[Delimiter="","", Columns=64, Encoding=65001, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.Csv])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Change Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{""Column1"", type text}, {""Column2"", type text}, {""Column3"", type text}, {""Column4"", type text}, {""Column5"", type text}, {""Column6" & _
        """, type text}, {""Column7"", type text}, {""Column8"", type text}, {""Column9"", type text}, {""Column10"", type text}, {""Column11"", type text}, {""Column12"", type text}, {""Column13"", type text}, {""Column14"", type text}, {""Column15"", type text}, {""Column16"", type text}, {""Column17"", type text}, {""Column18"", type text}, {""Column19"", type text}, {""C" & _
        "olumn20"", type text}, {""Column21"", type text}, {""Column22"", type text}, {""Column23"", type text}, {""Column24"", type text}, {""Column25"", type text}, {""Column26"", type text}, {""Column27"", type text}, {""Column28"", type text}, {""Column29"", type text}, {""Column30"", type text}, {""Column31"", type text}, {""Column32"", type text}, {""Column33"", type t" & _
        "ext}, {""Column34"", type text}, {""Column35"", type text}, {""Column36"", type text}, {""Column37"", type text}, {""Column38"", type text}, {""Column39"", type text}, {""Column40"", type text}, {""Column41"", type text}, {""Column42"", type text}, {""Column43"", type text}, {""Column44"", type text}, {""Column45"", type text}, {""Column46"", type text}, {""Column47" & _
        """, type text}, {""Column48"", type text}, {""Column49"", type text}, {""Column50"", type text}, {""Column51"", type text}, {""Column52"", type text}, {""Column53"", type text}, {""Column54"", type text}, {""Column55"", type text}, {""Column56"", type text}, {""Column57"", type text}, {""Column58"", type text}, {""Column59"", type text}, {""Column60"", type text}, {" & _
        """Column61"", type text}, {""Column62"", type text}, {""Column63"", type text}, {""Column64"", type text}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Change Type"""
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=""9 1copy"";Extended Properties=""""" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [9 1copy]")
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = "_9_1copy"
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("_9_1copy").ShowHeaders = False
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("_9_1copy").ShowTableStyleRowStripes = False
    Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Exit Sub
delQuery:
        Dim v
        For Each v In ActiveWorkbook.Queries
            If v.Name = sName Then _
                v.Delete
                Resume
        Next v
        MsgBox "Error No: " & Err.Number & vbLf & Err.Description
    Stop
    
End Sub
```

On running the code, it runs into an error

> "Run time error 1004: Application-Defined or Object-Defined error"

on line

```
.ListObject.DisplayName = "_9_1copy"
```

is highlighted on debugging.
Could you please help me fix the code and let me know what am I doing wrong?

Comment: None of the other lines in that function call use `ListObject` before setting the parameter. Why does that one, instead of just using `.DisplayName`?

Comment: Do you try this way **only to be sure that all fields are imported as text**?

Comment: @FaneDuru Yes, That is the aim. Also, once imported in the text format I have to rearrange the cell values in a certain way. All of that is ready and working good. Just the import functionality is needed

Comment: What type of csv do you try opening as text? I mean tab, comma etc. delimited and do you know how many columns does it have? Are there all the time the same number of columns?

Comment: comma delimited with quotes around all the values. No. of columns are always 64

Comment: Try changing that line to just `.DisplayName = "_9_1copy"`

Comment: Changing the like just to `.DisplayName = "_9_1copy` gives another error "Run time error 438. Object doesn't support this property or method".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for putting in your time and contribution. The issue was that the filepath that I was storing in the Variable using VBA can't be passed into the formula because formula is a power query. The work around was to store the file path value in one of the cells of the worksheet and then reference that cell as a parameter in the power query formula.

The working code is given below.

```
Sub importtext ()

    ' Part 1 of the code starts. Imports CSV in Text Format.
    
    ' Make Parameter table
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="Filepath", RefersToR1C1:="=Sheet1!R1C66"
    
    ' Ask for source file
    StrFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.csv),*.csv", , "Please select text file...")
    ' checks to make sure the user hasn't canceled the dialog.
    If StrFile = "False" Then
    MsgBox "No input file was selected. Process Aborted."
    End
    Else
    ' Put Value in parameter table so that we could pass it in power query.
    Range("BN1").Value = StrFile
    End If
    
    'Create a New Active Query, define the formula.
    SourceFormula = "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "  Filepath = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name=""Filepath""]}[Content]{0}[Column1]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents(Filepath),[Delimiter="","", Columns=64, Encoding=65001, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.Csv])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Change Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{""Column1"", type text}, {""Column2"", type text}, {""Column3"", type text}, {""Column4"", type text}, {""Column5"", type text}, {""Column6" & _
            """, type text}, {""Column7"", type text}, {""Column8"", type text}, {""Column9"", type text}, {""Column10"", type text}, {""Column11"", type text}, {""Column12"", type text}, {""Column13"", type text}, {""Column14"", type text}, {""Column15"", type text}, {""Column16"", type text}, {""Column17"", type text}, {""Column18"", type text}, {""Column19"", type text}, {""C" & _
            "olumn20"", type text}, {""Column21"", type text}, {""Column22"", type text}, {""Column23"", type text}, {""Column24"", type text}, {""Column25"", type text}, {""Column26"", type text}, {""Column27"", type text}, {""Column28"", type text}, {""Column29"", type text}, {""Column30"", type text}, {""Column31"", type text}, {""Column32"", type text}, {""Column33"", type t" & _
            "ext}, {""Column34"", type text}, {""Column35"", type text}, {""Column36"", type text}, {""Column37"", type text}, {""Column38"", type text}, {""Column39"", type text}, {""Column40"", type text}, {""Column41"", type text}, {""Column42"", type text}, {""Column43"", type text}, {""Column44"", type text}, {""Column45"", type text}, {""Column46"", type text}, {""Column47" & _
            """, type text}, {""Column48"", type text}, {""Column49"", type text}, {""Column50"", type text}, {""Column51"", type text}, {""Column52"", type text}, {""Column53"", type text}, {""Column54"", type text}, {""Column55"", type text}, {""Column56"", type text}, {""Column57"", type text}, {""Column58"", type text}, {""Column59"", type text}, {""Column60"", type text}, {" & _
            """Column61"", type text}, {""Column62"", type text}, {""Column63"", type text}, {""Column64"", type text}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Change Type"""
    
    'Add that new query to the workbook. If another query with same name exists, delete that.
    On Error GoTo delQuery
    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:=QueryName, _
                               Formula:=SourceFormula, _
                               Description:="This query will import all values in text format to prevent unwanted conversion of dates and numbers."
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    'Create the connection string
    ConnStr = "OLEDB;" & _
              "Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;" & _
              "Data Source=$Workbook$;" & _
              "Location=""sourcecsv"";" & _
              "Extended Properties="""""
            
    'Add a Query Table to our Worksheet
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=xlSrcExternal, _
                                LinkSource:=True, _
                                Source:=ConnStr, _
                                Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
    .CommandType = xlCmdSql
    .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [sourcecsv]")
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With

    ' Delete extra header row that is added while importing.
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).ShowHeaders = False
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).ShowTableStyleRowStripes = False
    Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete

' exit sub. Anything to be done after import should be before this comment.
Exit Sub

' Deletes query if there exists a query with the same name while we perform 1st part of the code.
delQuery:
        Dim v
        For Each v In ActiveWorkbook.Queries
            If v.Name = QueryName Then _
                v.Delete
                Resume
        Next v
        MsgBox "Error No: " & Err.Number & vbLf & Err.Description
    Stop
    
End Sub

end sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, use the next simpler code, able to open the csv/txt file with all fields **As Text**:

```
Sub testOpenAsText()
  Dim wb As Workbook, strFile As String
  Dim arrFlInf As Variant, i As Long, NrCol As Long
  
  NrCol = 5 'csv number of columns
  'If the number of columns is variable, the document can be opened twice, 
  'first time only counting the columns number, and second time As Text for the found number of columns...
  ReDim arrFlInf(1 To NrCol)
  For i = 1 To UBound(arrFlInf)
    arrFlInf(i) = Array(i, 2) 'Array(x, 2) means to be open AS TEXT, where x is the column number
  Next
  
  strFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.csv),*.csv", , "Please select CSV file...")

  Workbooks.OpenText fileName:=strFile, origin:=xlWindows, _
        StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, Comma:=False, Local:=False, FieldInfo:=arrFlInf
        
  Set wb = ActiveWorkbook 'do whatever you need with the document open with all its fields as Text...
End Sub
```

It assumes that the file type is comma delimited. It can be easily adapted to any delimter... Please, confirm that it open your document as text, without interpreting the date fields according to localization.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, this does load the data but still the dates and numbers are formatted. It doesn't import them as a text value. zeroes in front of the numbers are truncated.

Answer (score 0):

```
xlsObj=CreateObject("Excel.Application");
xlsObj.Visible = 0;
xlsObj.ScreenUpdating = 0;
xlsObj.EnableEvents = 0;
xlsObj.DisplayAlerts = 0; 
xlsObj.DecimalSeparator = ".";
xlsObj.ThousandsSeparator = "";
xlsObj.UseSystemSeparators = 0;
xlsOpenFile = xlsObj.Workbooks.Open(strFileName,0,1);
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the OP's question.