# Disable excel convert string to date while opening csv file

Tags: excel, vba, vsto, excel-dna

I am trying to disable excel to convert normail string like 1-2 to date 1/2/2021, I know there is no default settings to disable this behavior.

I am wondering whether there is any event to be fired before converting or any automatically way to convert back.

Any possible way is acceptable.

I am glad to implement through `VBA`, `Excel VSTO Addin` or `excel-dna`.

Comment: Does this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62622781/import-csv-without-data-being-formatted-to-dates-and-numbers) help?

Comment: What does *"opening csv"* exactly mean (open/import/VBA/…) there are many ways to get CSV into Excel? Do you have some [mcve] for that (including example data)? This should work if you define the column as text during import. Have a look at the "Data" ribbon menu and use the button "From Text/CSV". There you can specify which datatype a column is (text will not convert to date then).

Comment: You need to **import** instead of **open**. When you **import** you will have the opportunity to designate the column containing these values as **Text**.  You can **import** using VBA or Power Query (or the legacy import wizard). To make it easier for users, you can tie the process to a Button.

Comment: @RaymondWu no, I need to keep string while I double click to open the csv file

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I mean double click the file to open. I did not want to use import feature `From Text/CSV`,

Comment: @Edward in that case i don't think there is a solution.

Comment: @Edward With double click there is no way to achieve this! Double click on CSV files (to open in Excel) is the worst solution you can choose as you have no control about what happens. So you will have to use any other feature where you can control that (what RaymondWU and Ron Rosenfeld already suggested).

Answer (score 0):

Using VBA, set the column(s) that will contain the dates to 'text'.

ie Columns("A:A").NumberFormat = "@"

If you are opening the file from within Excel, use the 'import wizard' and make sure the date columns are set to 'text'.

An alternative method is to update the data to include an apostrophe before the date but that is getting desperate.

Comment: Note that `Columns("A:A").NumberFormat = "@"` has no effect if you use the "import wizard" it will use the format you choose in the wizard. So this line does not make any sense.

Comment: It depends on how it being used. If there was copy/paste involved, then that would be what you use. I agree, the 'import wizard' would be the preferred approach but it does not cover every way that VBA gets used.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to achieve this on double click in Explorer (to open the CSV in Excel).

The only alternatives where you have control what happens are:
Import using VBA or Power Query (or the legacy import wizard).

For examle: [Import CSV without data being formatted to dates and numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62622781/import-csv-without-data-being-formatted-to-dates-and-numbers)

Comment: Is there any add-in event which can be used to save the file which I double-clicked? I think if there is, i will be able to save a copy and then restore the value programmly.

Comment: Not that I know of, Excel will process the file before it is opened. So even if there was any event the changes would have happened before the event triggers.